# Kivy Rules and Properties

Tags: android, python, kivy

I'm trying to have the text of my InputMaker Button be specified when I apply the ModuleMaker rule in ModuleLayout. However, no text is showing up (i.e "Yo") when I run the program. Source seems to be working fine, but text is not.

```
   <InputMaker@Button>:
        text: self.text
        pos: self.pos
        size: self.size
        background_normal:'./images/modone.png'

    <ModuleMaker>:
        size: 150, 150
        source: self.source
        text: self.text

        canvas:
            Ellipse:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
                source: self.source
        InputMaker:
            id: btnone
            text: self.text
            pos: self.parent.pos



    <ModuleLayout>:
        moduleone: one
        moduletwo: two
        modulethree: three

        ModuleMaker:
            id: one
            center_y: root.center_y
            x: root.x +300
            source: './images/modone.png'
            text: "YO"

        ModuleMaker:
            id: two
            center_y: root.center_y
            x: root.x+400
            source: './images/modtwo.png'

        ModuleMaker:
            id: three
            center_y: root.center_y
            x: root.x+500
            source: './images/modthree.png'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your InputMaker rule references self.text when you really want to bind to root.text.

Comment: It throws an error saying that None is not allowed and doesn't doesn't anything.